# Early 80’s short story about invisible gremlins viewable only with special glasses

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

These gremlins were everywhere causing mayhem, pulling on ladders, etc. Their antics were sometimes fairly innocent but also occasionally dangerous.

They could only be seen through the special glasses that the protagonist found.  I believe the glasses had belonged to a relative who had died, but I don’t remember.

And once the gremlins realize he could see them, he merely pulled the glasses off but I can’t remember anything else from the story.

Comment: Hi there. Two things: you say it's a short story but tagged that with [books]. Did you mean it's a short book, it is that an actual short story (10-20k words)? Second, what belonged to the relative, the glasses or the Gremlins? Could you please [edit] that in?

Comment: It’s an actual short story, but was unable to find that tag. Also, made the requested edits to clarify it was the glasses that had belonged to a relative. Essentially magic glasses that allowed him to see these gremlins (my word) operating in our world.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to "Pixie Ointment," from *[Tales of Enchantment](https://books.google.com/books?id=QBjNjQcGvh8C)*, also published as *The Kincaid's Book of Witches, Goblins, Ogres and Fantasy*; it may or may not have been an adaptation of an earlier folktale.

In the story, a woman receives an ointment that she puts on her eyelids—to discover that it enables her to see that pixies up to all sorts of mischief, especially stealing.